# get 7 digit after point in java

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal, divide

I want seven digit after dividing a integer,i have `ddhh.mmmmm` lat long I have to convert it `dd.(hhmmmm/60)` with 7 digit after point.

My code:

```
public static String getCoordinates(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
        String mm = data.substring(2).replace(".", "");
        int int_mm = Integer.parseInt(mm);
        double d_mm = int_mm / 60.00000000;
        String s_mm = Double.toString(d_mm);
        s_mm = s_mm.replace(".", "");
        String s_dd = data.substring(0, 2);
        return s_dd + "." + s_mm;
    }

Input
2838.9544
Output
28.64924

Input
7716.7731
Output
77.2795516666666667
```

two same input but is not same how can i solve it?

Comment: Search about `NumberFormat` in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
Double result=Double.parseDouble(s_dd + "." + s_mm);
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");  
return formatter.format(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.math.BigDecimal
```

in java has the following future for your problem.

```
double d = Double.valueOf(152452+"."+45545545);
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
bd = bd.setScale(7, RoundingMode.CEILING);
```

In this example bd is equals to `152452.4554555`

Comment: You should use the `BigDecimal(java.lang.String)` constructor to avoid loss of precision.